# Matlab 2D contour using X-Y coordinate data

Tags: matlab, contour

I have a set of data that looks likes the following:

```
!Sr.#    x-coord.    y-coord     potential at (x,y)
  1       0.0000     1.0000      0.3508
  2       0.7071     0.7071      2.0806
  .       ....       ....        ....
  .       ....       ....        ....
 1000    0.0000     -1.0000      0.5688
```

I need to generate a 2D contour for the above data where the value of the potential will be plotted at the corresponding (x,y) location on the 2D contour map. I believe that in order to be able to plot a 2D contour using the contour command in Matlab, I will have to use a 2D matrix (which will essentially contain potential values in my case). How do I create a 2D matrix for this case? Or is there a workaround which can altogether avoid a 2D matrix and still give a 2D contour. The x-y coodinate data I have is not in any particular order but can be arranged if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into this problem myself, and have found an incredible solution from a stackoverflow member, [John D'Errico](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/679), i.e. woodchips.  His [package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit) on Matlab Central called `gridfit,` will solve your problem handily.  Here's my own example, but John has much better ones in his incredible documentation and demo files.

```
% first, get some random x,y coordinates between -3 and 3
% to allow the peaks() function to look somewhat meaningful
x = rand(10,1)*6 - 3;
y = rand(10,1)*6 - 3;
% calculate the peaks function for this points
z = peaks(x,y);
% now, decide the grid we want to see, -3 to 3 at 0.1 intervals
% will be fine for this crude test
xnodes = -3:0.1:3;
ynodes = -3:0.1:3;
% now, all gridfit, notice, no sorting!  no nothing!
% just tell it the rectangular grid you want, and give it
% the raw data.  It will use linear algebra and other robust
% techniques to fit the function to the grid points
[zg,xg,yg] = gridfit(x,y,z,xnodes,ynodes);
% finally, plot the data, Viola!
contour(xg,yg,zg)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to gridfit. It is almost what I needed!! 

What I understand from your test code is that gridfit needs a rectangular domain to fit the original data, i.e. by using,

    xnodes = -3:0.1:3;
    ynodes = -3:0.1:3;

The original data that I have may not always be for a rectangular domain (eg. an annular region in 2D). In which case I would end up in false data points inside and outside the annular region with the use of gridfit. A not so clean way out of this might be to mask the output at points outside the region of interest.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrarily scattered data, look at [TriScatteredInterp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html) as an alternative to gridfit.