# How to draw 2D contour in MATLAB from a set of unsorted x-y coordinates in a non-rectangular domain

Tags: matlab, contour

I have the electric potential value at a set of unsorted points. I know the x-y coordinates of all points and the mesh is like the following.
[image]

Now I want to draw the potential contour in the blue region. There is a similar problem here [Matlab 2D contour using X-Y coordinate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968867/matlab-2d-contour-using-x-y-coordinate-data). However, it only gives answer on how to draw this contour in a rectangular region, but what I need is to draw contours only in the blue region. Is there anybody who can help me with this? Thank you so much.

If we assume the size of the rectangular is Lx1 by Hy1 and the size of the right one is Lx2 by Hy2, the code I tried to connect two contours is as follows:

```
xdim1 = 0:dx:Lx1;
ydim1 = 0:dy:Hy1;
xdim2 = Lx1:dx:(Lx1+Lx2);
ydim2 = (Hy1-Hy2):dy:Hy1;
figure
contourf(xdim1, ydim1, phi1); %phi1 is the sorted potential value in this region
hold on
contourf(xdim2, ydim2, phi2); %phi2 is the sorted potential value in this region
hold off
```

However, this code failed. Is there any bugs in this piece of code?

Possible solution:
Thanks @Inox, @ysakamoto and @R. Schifini for their suggestions. I tried to assign the potential in the white rectangular region to be NaN and plot contour in the outermost rectangular region. The plots looks good.

Comment: If you can do it for a rectangle, you can do it for your grid. You can either join the contour of the rectangle 0<x<1 0<y<1, and the 1<x<2 0.5<y<1. Or create the countour of 0<x<2 0<y<1 and eliminate 1<x<2 0<y<0.5 (and put some very high values on that blank rectangles). Just need to set the same parameters in whatever algorithm you're using

Comment: How to join the contours of the two rectangles together? I tried to use "hold on" and "hold off" to draw two contours on one figure, but it failed.

Comment: `hold on` and `off` works on countour. What do you mean by "unsorted x-y coordinates"? If it is not sorted grid-wise, then contour does not even work on a rectangular domain.

Comment: @ysakamoto Sorry my mistake. When I plot the contour, I've sorted the phi based on the grid. I've modified my problem and added in a piece of code which is used to draw contour. However, it seems that only the first contour is shown. But if I plot them separately, they're fine. Can you take a look at the code to see if there is any problem? Thank you!

Comment: See if this helps: try using the whole rectangular region in the figure and then setting the values of the empty region to NaN.

Comment: @R.Schifini Looks pretty good! But there is still one contour around the corner in the white region. Is it because the potential on my boundary is not NaN?