# Contour coordinates

Tags: matlab, contour

I don't know if this is possible, but I would like to be able to plot contour lines in a given latitude and longitude. 
I have an ocean model that gives me the currents in direction u and v at location x (longitude) and y(latitude). 
Using the quiver function (quiver(x,y,u,v)) and the following code, I managed to map the currents in the Gulf of Lions.

```
Step=8 %Only use 1 in 8 data point so the arrows don't overlap too much
figure
q=quiver(lonu(1:Step:681,1:Step:711),latu(1:Step:681,1:Step:711),U,V,0)
```

[image]
As you can see, the model is more detailed close to the coast, because it uses the following grid:

[image]
*Source: Briton, Florence, et al. "High‐resolution modelling of ocean circulation can reveal retention spots important for biodiversity conservation." Aquatic Conservation: Marine and Freshwater Ecosystems 28.4 (2018): 882-893.*

The problem with this is that when I try to use contour or contourf it completely loses the shape of the gulf of Lions due to the choice of grid:

```
figure
contourf(sqrt(U.^2+V.^2))%The vector of the current is X=sqrt(U^2+V^2) see pythagoras
colorbar
```

[image]
So eventually, I would like to be able to indicate the strength of the current using contourf while indicating the direction using quiver. **So how do I reshape the picture given by contourf into something realistic using coordinates?**
I checked question [Matlab 2D contour using X-Y coordinate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968867/matlab-2d-contour-using-x-y-coordinate-data) but I don't understand how to use the proposed function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You suddenly decided to avoid imputing the data that gives the shape, `X` and `Y` input parameters.

```
contourf(lonu(1:Step:681,1:Step:711),latu(1:Step:681,1:Step:711),sqrt(U.^2+V.^2))%The vector of the current is X=sqrt(U^2+V^2) see pythagoras
```